# Will I lose my data is I "write MBR partition table to disk and exit" in Gparted?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, mbr

I've never used Ubuntu before and I'm trying to install it. Apparently Ubuntu thinks I don't have Windows 7 installed, so I don't have the option to install it alongside Windows.

I found a tutorial that is supposedly going to fix this problem using gparted and the fixparts command. The commands are `sudo apt-get install gdisk` , then `sudo fixparts /dev/sdc` and finally `"W"` for the option `write MBR partition table to disk and exit`

I did not proceed as I got a warning that said it will overwrite all existing partitions.

Will I lose all the data on the drive doing this ?

Or will it still be there ?

Comment: First install gparted.And see whether the windows partition exists or not.

Comment: The partitions and disks are all detected. I don't want to install it on my SSD with Windows 7 installed, but my other 1TB hard drive. I created a 100GB partition for Ubuntu, but I believe the problem is simply that Ubuntu does not detect my OS on the SSD

Comment: During ubuntu installation,is there any `something else` option.And also upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: I tried getting screenshots, but I can't really use my mouse in Ubuntu. Could you just tell me whether this warning will erase everything I have on the disk? That is really what my question was.

Comment: Nevermind. I gave up on Ubuntu. I tried everything. I eventually tried installing Ubuntu using the "something else" option, then it restarted and went straight into Windows 7. No bootloader or anything and I couldn't get into Ubuntu.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/382242/after-installing-windows-8-next-to-ubuntu-i-can-only-boot-8/382253#382253