# Ubuntu is installed, but computer just boots to windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I properly(i think) installed ubuntu along side with windows 8.1 which is my computers
first OS.  I have done the "Try ubuntu without installing" option and then trying to install and it tells me that ubuntu is already installed.

The problem is that I cannot
get ubuntu to boot.  My computer jumps straight to Windows 8.1 everytime.  I have enable legacy booting, and tried everything i can think of.  Any suggestions?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/382242/after-installing-windows-8-next-to-ubuntu-i-can-only-boot-8/382253#382253

Comment: have you tried boot repair yet??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is probably because your grub isn't installed decently.

try this link:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

and good luck!