# Can't permanently install ubuntu on an Acer Predator g3-710?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, acer

I've already downloaded the iso image changed the BIOS settings, booted into the usb drive and gone through the installation process, but when I restart the system it boots straight into windows instead of ubuntu, I can't seem to get a GRUB menu up or anything. the only thing I can do is hit f12 and go into the boot menu where it says :
try ubuntu without installing
install ubuntu
etc.
What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8 and Ubuntu Dual Boot Issues](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502384/windows-8-and-ubuntu-dual-boot-issues) If you don't think this is a duplicate, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this problem? I just got a Predator g3-710 and am having the same exact problem - I installed 17.10 and it installed ok, but when I  boot there's no option for ubuntu, it just goes into windows.

Comment: no I haven't been able to fix it sadly, I found some stuff on one of the acer forums regarding a similar problem and tried it but it didn't work.